# How can I compare two dates of different types in Python?

Tags: python, date, time

I get a date from a file in the following format:

```
2018-07-20 05:16:12
```

I need to compare this date with a file's last modified date.
I can get the last modified date in the following format:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime('test-reboot-3.txt'))
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 27, 7, 58, 15, 541916)
```

How can I compare the latter date with the above mentioned date from my file?

Comment: Use dateutil to parse dates, and convert the date to a datetime object. Once both dates are in datetime object format you can use == operator to compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert your string to datetime object and then compare.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
d1 = "2018-07-20 05:16:12"
d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

d2 = datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 27, 7, 58, 15, 541916) 

print(d2 - d1)
```

**Output:**

```
7 days, 2:42:03.541916
```